# Use Python for loop to calculate summation of squared numbers?

Tags: python, for-loop

I need to calculate the summation of the squares of the first 20 odd numbers. (1,3,5...39)
I first needed to display the squared odds, which i've done:

```
x=1.
while x<40:
    print(x**2)
    x=x+2
```

Output:

```
1.0
9.0
25.0
49.0
81.0
121.0
169.0
225.0
289.0
361.0
441.0
529.0
625.0
729.0
841.0
961.0
1089.0
1225.0
1369.0
1521.0
```

How do I now calculate the summation of these values?

Comment: Create a variable initialize to `0` outside your loop and add `x**2` to it inside your loop. Alternatively use `sum()` and pass it a comprehension:  `sum(x**2 for x in range(1, 40, 2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run

```
def sum_first_square_odds(n):
    val = sum(x**2 for x in range(1, n*2, 2))
    return val

print(sum_first_square_odds(20))
```

By the way, it's:

> 10660

Comment: Thank you so much! I put print(sum(x**2 for x in range(1,40,2))) outside of the for loop and that did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the one-liner given by other users, or if you want to break it down, use the code here:

```
x = 1
summation = 0
first_x_odds = 20
counter = 0
while counter < first_x_odds:
    summation = summation + x**2
    x = x + 2
    counter = counter + 1
print(summation)
```